# How to show current file in sidebar explorer with focus in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a shortcut to show current file in sidebar with focus on that file (when sidebar is closed)? Basicaly combination of `workbench.files.action.showActiveFileInExplorer` and `workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer`

Like in Resharper `Shift+Alt+L`: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Locating_a_File_in_Solution_Explorer.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Extension [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros#overview):

[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

```json
"macros": {
    "showFileAndFocus": [
        "workbench.files.action.showActiveFileInExplorer",
        "workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer"
    ]
}
```

[keybindings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)

```json
{
    "key": "shift+alt+l",
    "command": "macros.showFileAndFocus"
}
```

Comment: I think it works! I just needed to switch order of `showActiveFileInExplorer` and `focusFilesExplorer`.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need a macro, you can use the `focusFilesExplorer` shortcut alone:

```json
{
    "key": "shift+alt+l",
    "command": "workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Comment: That does not seem to focus the current file, only the explorer itself

Comment: @AndrewStarostin Been using this for a couple of years now and it works great. Perhaps the file you are testing with is not in the explorer so it cant focus it.

Comment: Confirming this works. I've used `ctrl+m` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me is

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+m", # you can add whatever key combination you prefer here
    "command": "workbench.files.action.showActiveFileInExplorer",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }
```

Add this in `keybindings.json`

To open `keybindings.json` Go to `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`

Then click on the `Open Keyboard Shortcuts(JSON)` icon in the top-right position